# Install Play Framework Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, playframework, cmd, installation

I'm trying to install the Play! Framework on Windows 8.1, I added path and I've tried to run 'play' command, and the output is:

```
Error during sbt execution: Could not find configuration file
'file:////c:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/play-2.2.2/framework/sbt/play.boot.properties'.
Searched:
        file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/play-2.2.2/
        file:/C:/Users/Username/
        file:/C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/play-2.2.2/framework/sbt/
```

What can I do?

Comment: You should try to install play in a directory that doesn't include spaces (= not "Program Files"). This can be the cause of your problem.

Comment: I'm so noob with cmd!!! That's my solution, thank you so much. You should answer this Question to define as solution.

Comment: thanks, I've posted my message as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to install play in a directory that doesn't include spaces (= not `Program Files`). This can be the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

copy the play framework folder to c:\ it worked for me